# How to do install gcc-4.5-arm-linux-gnueabi in ubuntu 13.04?

Tags: 13.04

I tried  `sudo apt-get install gcc-4.5-arm-linux-gnueabi`

I got this error:

```
E: Package 'gcc-4.5-arm-linux-gnueabi' has no installation candidate
```

How I can download it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Ubuntu 13.04, the version is 4.7. Is there are particular reason why you need 4.5 and can't use the later 4.7?

It is possible to search for packages in the APT repositories and to get better results, you can use regular expressions:

```
$ sudo apt-cache search gcc-4.*-arm-linux-gnueabi$
gcc-4.7-arm-linux-gnueabi - GNU C compiler
gcc-4.7-multilib-arm-linux-gnueabi - GNU C compiler (multilib files)
```

In short:

```
$ - marks that the string matching should end there
* - matches any character
```

References:

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/man8/apt-cache.8.html

http://www.zytrax.com/tech/web/regex.htm

Comment: I am building Opencv For CARMA so that i want to download 4.5 version only. thanks for help.